# Loosing shift+select when in lattice

Tags: selection-tools

I'm using lattice and have selected a certain number of vertices but every now and then I try to shift+select other and blender 'loses' its select box. I'm pretty sure I'm must be doing something wrong...any idea what it might be?

Tks

Comment: When you say it "loses its select box" do you mean the control points you have selected already become deselected? Or do you mean that Border Select doesn't work?  I think you mean you press Shift and Right click, and the other points become deselected?? If so, maybe you're pressing the mouse button before you have the Shift down. Make sure you press Shift first, and hold it down while clicking.

Comment: Border select wasn't working, but now I realise that I didn't have it selected on the menu cause I'm currently using the gizmo...so now eeeevery time I have to switch back to selection box tool..but thanks!